# Complex Integral Over an Ellipse

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose we had a function defined as
$$
S(\zeta) = \zeta - \sqrt{\zeta^2 - c^2}
$$

and we wish to evaluate
$$
\oint_\gamma \frac{S(\zeta)}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta,
$$
where $\gamma$ is the (positively orientated) ellipse
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad a > b > 0,\quad c^2= a^2-b^2
$$
and $z$ lies outside $\gamma$. First I notice that by Cauchy's theorem,
$$
\oint_\gamma \frac{\zeta}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta = 0
$$
since the integrand is holomorphic inside $\gamma$. So I am left with
$$
-\oint_\gamma \frac{ \sqrt{\zeta^2 - c^2}}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta
$$
Is there a clever way to evaluate this without using a parameterisation? Letting
$$
\zeta = a \cos t + ib\sin t, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi
$$
leads me to
$$
-\oint_\gamma \frac{ \sqrt{\zeta^2 - c^2}}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(b\cos t + ia\sin t)^2}{iz-ia\cos t + b\sin t} \, dt
$$
which looks hard to evaluate.

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ is multivalued function. Should one choose a branch first?

Comment: The chosen branch is such that for $\sqrt{\zeta^2 - c^2} > 0$ on the interval $(c, \infty)$ (I forgot to mention $c > 0$), with a branch cut $[-c,c]$.

Comment: then contract your integral to the branch cut, and reverse the path of integration. your integral is then equal to the residues at $z$ and $\infty$ times a phase which is due to the discontinuity over the cut

Answer (score 1):

First observe the the branch points corresponds to the two foci of the ellipse that constitutes your path of integration,therefore  the branch cut is inside $\gamma$ . 
Now we do  a little trick, instead of picking up the singularities inside of our contour, we pick up the ones at its outside (because it is easier to count residues then integrating around a branch cut). 
This yields

$$
I(z)=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{S(\zeta)}{z-\zeta}d\zeta=-2\pi i(\text{Res}(\zeta=\infty)+\text{Res}(\zeta=z))
$$

Note the minus sign, which stemms from the fact the we encircle the poles in clockwise direction now. The residues are given (choosing the correct branch of $\log$ which induces that $\pm i=e^{\pm i \pi/2}$)

$$
\text{Res}(\zeta=\infty)=0\\
\text{Res}(\zeta=z)=z-\sqrt{z^2-c^2}
$$

and therefore

> $$
> I(z)=2\pi i(\sqrt{z^2-c^2}-z)
> $$

Comment: OK! And if $z$ was inside $\gamma$, the same trick can be used, giving zero?

Comment: it seems so, yes